# Header key in DocuSign Webhook connect

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

What are the keys of username/ password in webhook connect header response? I tried with username/ password/ X-DocuSign-Password/ X-DocuSign-UserName but is not

Answer (score 0):

webhook connect response is sent from DocuSign to your web server following events that occured and based on your configuraiton.

No password is ever going to be sent from DocuSign.

You may be referring to the header that was used in the past to make API calls before OAuth 2.0 was implemented. That is an insecure way to authenticate and therefor no longer allowed for new applications that are under development.